# Django contact form with class based views

Tags: python, django

Can anyone explain me how to make send email form on page.

So my forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    adults = forms.IntegerField()
    children = forms.IntegerField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
class TourDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Tour
    template_name = 'tours/tour-detail.html'
    form_class = forms.ContactForm
    success_url = 'tours.html'
```

As far as i understand i need to get data from request  , but i dont know how to do it. There are a lot of information in function based views, but i didnt get how to do it in class based views.

And it would be nice of you to explain where should i put send_mail function. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [did you read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: [also this for Email](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/build-a-django-contact-form-with-email-backend)